# Winforms MDI Style Behavior using Blazor WASM?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, blazor-webassembly

I'm a veteran C# WinForms developer and I started a new greenfield E.R.P. project, last year.  Wanting to build something that lasts for the next 20 years, I did my research on the next big technology to use.  Because of my C# knowledge and a desire to move to a browser app, I decided on Blazor Wasm (Client).  I built an API to handle all the CRUD - works perfect.  Now, I'm building the Blazor app and have the first several pages done.  The pages are functional work areas, like "Setup Items", or "Enter Orders".  The "MainLayout" page loads a Navigation Menu so the user can open different pages.

In my past WinForms app, it was an MDI so a user could be setting up a new item in one screen, then enter orders in another, and be able to switch around different windows at will.  The menu stayed visible so that they could open new forms (documents) as needed.

Now that I'm using the new browser app, I'm figuring out that if I load a new page, it changes the current page to the new one and reloads the menu.  In fact, the whole site reloads.  If I load the new page into a new tab, it's like a whole new site instance is loaded.  I actually created a separate layout and loaded the work pages separately from MainLayout and the page will load but as if the services have not been loaded (things like a toaster don't work).  So I've searched the net and it appears that I may be in uncharted territory in wanting a web-app to act like a WinForms MDI.

Obviously, I'm one of the C# guys trying to get into Blazor Web.  Is it possible to get Blazor WASM to behave like an MDI?

Comment: It might be possible, but why would you want to?  An obsessive focus on mimicking Winforms led to the debacle that we now call Web Forms.  ASP.NET MVC was a direct response to that.  We don't even use IFrames anymore, for the most part.  In short, there are now better models.

Comment: Thank you Robert Harvey.  I suspected that this might be the first response.  You are right that I am trying to mimic something that worked well in WinForms.  It's tried and true.  And I should consider packing more functionality into a single page, for sure.  But there are security considerations for each page and I wouldn't want somebody entering sales to be able manage pricing or items, which would be on a different page.  Also, how do you explain to a user that they will lose their sales order screen they just spend several minutes entering a new order, if they go to a different page?

Comment: `how to you explain to a user that they will lose their sales order screen they just spend several minutes entering a new order, if they go to a different page?` -- Amazon doesn't have this problem.  I can leave an item in my cart for days or weeks, if I want to.  I can close my browser and open it again tomorrow, and my item will still be there.

Comment: What you are saying is correct, no doubt.  And I do have a save function that would save the order.  I'm referring to just starting an order and not finished to a point where you can save.  This is an ERP system with sophisticated customer, shipping, and pricing models that often have to be updated before an order can be fully entered.  And before you even begin entering items.  So there is inevitable page switching going on.  Is it normal in web apps to get work done in page #1,2,3 before you can proceed to re-opening page the original page?  Maybe use dialogs for prep-work?

Comment: Is this what you're after?  https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/steppers.html

Comment: Or this?  http://materialdesignadmin.com/form-wizard.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think it's more that he wants users to be able to have a sales order open in one tab and a manage product form open in another and possibly many other tabs open. If he sets the links to open in a new browser tab Blazor is reloading the entire application.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, This discussion has been great for me.  I realize that I need to learn how to evolve and use the tools available to achieve the same effect in a different way.  I've spent a lot of time going back and reviewing the Dialog Box tools, as well as the slider and other Material Design tools.  I am using DevExpress Blazor, which is still evolving.  Either way, I can incorporate different tools with better UX design to achieve the same result.  Thank you for helping me work through this!  Please post an answer so I can approve it.  Thanks to you and DotNetDublin for the advice.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Note that dialog boxes are very expensive from a UI perspective.  I only use them when I literally want the user to stop whatever they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The below video might be of interest in terms of splitting your page into panels.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNDd7moZJ4c

Comment: I watched the video on sliders and this is a very cool tool to use.  But this app could have users with half dozen pages open at a time while they work during the day.  And the page opening/closing needs to be dynamic without predetermined panel count.  Thank you for the idea!